# ActiveRecord query returning nothing after small change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  def self.all_matches(email, ....)

    #blockades and blockades_by is from amistad gem

    ids = Profile.find_by_email(email).blockades.pluck(:id) + Profile.find_by_email(email).blockades_by.pluck(:id)

     self.order('random()').
             where(:approval_status => Profile::ApprovalStatus::APPROVED).
             where('id NOT IN (?)', ids).
             where.not(:email => email)
```

When I added the

```
             where('id NOT IN (?)', ids).
```

It returns nothing. Before I added it it returned 4 elements.

when I went into console, grabbed the profile and searched blocked and blockades by they were both empty.

= (

any idea why??

Comment: Try NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists
When the subquery returns even one null, NOT IN will not match any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return nothing if ids is an empty array. You should skip running `where('id NOT IN (?)', ids)` when the array is empty.

Comment: Here is an explenation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877100/postgres-not-in-null-gives-no-result